# Call event registration with specific language through Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, civievent, localisation, i18n

I am using the latest Wordpress with Polylang and CiviCRM versions. I try to call the online event registration form in both German and English, but I don't know how to do it.

How can I force CiviCRM to switch to a specific language?  The &lcMesssages=de_DE parameter has no effect at all, neither does &lang=de.

Inherit language from CMS also does not work - I cannot even see a pattern. When I call CiviCRM from the Dashboard, it's always the current language, just from Wordpress itself, it does not work at all.

But there must be a way to force CiviCRM to use a specific language - or not? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Polylang is not supported by CiviCRM yet but it should change soon : I have just submitted a patch here : https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11312

If you still have a need for this functionality, you should try it and confirm if it resolves the problem.

To make it work with the patch :

1. Install Polylang and configure at least 2 languages
   [image: polylang - languages config wordpress]
2. Configure CiviCRM in multiligual mode with 2 languages and set "Inherit CMS Language"
   [image: settings - localization wordpress]
3. In civicrm.settings.php, uncomment as needed lines like : `define('CIVICRM_LANGUAGE_MAPPING_xx_XX')`  (to resolve ambiguity between language short 'fr' and language long form 'fr_FR' or 'fr_CA')
4. Create a contribution page and translate at least the title
5. Add a page with the shortcode to the contribution page and translate it to the second language
   [image: edit page shortcode and language wordpress]
6. You should be able to go to one page you've created and switch language to have another version of the same form